# awk patern search for all item in array

Tags: arrays, awk

Working awk code:

```
BEGIN {bla}
/patern1/ {userFunction(input1)} 
...                              
/paternN/ {userFunction(inputN)} 
END {bla}
```

Now I try to store `paternX` and `inputX` using array and use a for loop

Actually tried:

```
for (i in patern)
    $0 ~ /patern[i]/ {userFunction(input[i])}

$ ... awk:38: for (i in patern)
$ ... awk:38: ^ syntax error
```

Or

```
$0 ~ /for (i in patern)/ {userFunction(input[i])}

$ ... awk:40:         $0 ~ /patern[i]/ {userFunction(input[s])}
$ ... awk:40:                          ^ syntax error
```

Simplified example

```
cat >> inputs << EOF
1
2
3
1
1
EOF
```

Working

```
awk '
/1/{print "one"}
/2/{print "two"}' inputs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` -- and also `if` -- is a statement that can only go in the 'action' part of an awk rule, not the 'condition' part; and `//` is only for *literal* patterns (regexps) not variables:

```
{ for( i in patterns ) if( $0 ~ patterns[i] ) userFunction( inputs[i] ) }
```

However, since awk array subscripts can be any string, also called 'associative', rather than keep two arrays in sync you can use one:

```
BEGIN{ pat_inp["pattern1"]="input1"; pat_inp["pattern2"]="input2"; ... }
{ for( i in pat_inp ) if( $0 ~ i ) userFunction( pat_inp[i] ) }
```